# Celery inspect remove 10 items limit

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I need to get the worker queue size using python and Celery. The code works fine, but result is limited to 10 items. Is there any way to get entire list of queued tasks? I get 100+ items, but only 10 are being returned

```
res = i.reserved() # Names of tasks reserved by the worker
reserved_count = len(res[queue_name])
```

Entire code:

```
    app = Celery('myapp', broker='redis://redis:6379/0')

    # Tist of queue names to inspect
    queue_names = ['celery@worker.photos', 'celery@worker.videos']
    queue_info = {}

    # Iterate through the queue names
    for queue_name in queue_names:
    
        i = app.control.inspect([queue_name])

        a = i.active() # Names of tasks currently being executed by the worker
        active_count = len(a[queue_name])

        res = i.reserved() # Names of tasks reserved by the worker
        reserved_count = len(res[queue_name])

        pretty_queue_name = queue_name.replace('celery@worker.', '')

        queue_info[pretty_queue_name] = {
            'active': active_count,
            'reserved': reserved_count,
            'total': active_count + reserved_count
        }
       
    return queue_info
```

Comment: Are you scheduling tasks? you know you still have registered and scheduled tasks to go through. If you just need count it would be better just to count from queue redis collection